# Navigate to google and perform the manual actions like searching using Java (without Selenium) , a kind of Java Bot

Tags: java

Scenario:I want to open the browser and search.All the manual actions like opening browser, searching, navigating to the results.
Conditions:Without selenium should be coded in java.

I have tried with Jsoup, after opening the browsers storing all the html content into a doc file and then parsing it using Jsoup and then finding the element but after finding the element ,i want to click and pass value into search box.
Any Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Maybe with JavaFX WebView https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html
Anyway, you will end up with something that is like Selenium.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.